# FluentMigrator updated 1.2.1 to 3.3.1

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I have this TableExtensions static class that I am using fine with FluentMigrator 1.2.1 now I updated the package to 3.3.1 and getting this error. I dont know that this error means a requires a receiver?

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table("Sentences")
            .WithIdColumn()
            .WithCommonColumns();
    }



 public static ICreateTableWithColumnOrSchemaOrDescriptionSyntax WithCommonColumns(this ICreateTableWithColumnOrSchemaOrDescriptionSyntax table)
        {
            return table.WithColumn("Added").AsDateTime().NotNullable().WithDefaultValue(SystemMethods.CurrentUTCDateTime)
                   .WithColumn("Modified").AsDateTime().Nullable()
                   .WithColumn("Deleted").AsDateTime().Nullable()
                   .WithColumn("IsDeleted").AsBoolean().NotNullable().WithDefaultValue(false);
        }
```

> Severity   Code    Description File    Project Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1929  'ICreateTableColumnOptionOrWithColumnSyntax' does not contain a definition for 'WithCommonColumns' and the best extension method overload 'TableExtensions.WithCommonColumns(ICreateTableWithColumnOrSchemaOrDescriptionSyntax)' requires a receiver of type 'ICreateTableWithColumnOrSchemaOrDescriptionSyntax'

Comment: The method `WithIdColumn` now returns a `ICreateTableColumnOptionOrWithColumnSyntax`, but your extension method expects a `ICreateTableWithColumnOrSchemaOrDescriptionSyntax `

Comment: Should the extension method return `ICreateTableWithColumnOrSchemaOrDescriptionSyntax `?

Comment: I don't know. What does the expression after `return` return?

Comment: it return `ICreateTableColumnOptionOrWithColumnSyntax`

Comment: You should probably return that from your extension method, then